# React Native Loading image off API Fetch data

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native! And having problems with properly loading the image off the JSON that I get from JsonPlaceHolder API. I set the state of the photos and the titles. The titles were able to load, however, photos were not be able to load properly. I did search and there are suggestions to replace http to https call would fix it. But No luck here. Please help! And Thank in Advance!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
  Image, 
  StyleSheet,
  Text, 
  View, 
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
    this.state = {
      photos: '',
      titles: ''
    };
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = async () => {
    let response = await fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/1');
    let json = await response.json();
    this.setState({titles: json.title, photos: json.url.replace('http','https')});
  };

render() {
    console.log(this.state.photos)
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image 
          source={{uri: this.state.photos}} 
          style={{height: 600, width: 600}}
          resizeMode= 'cover'
        />
        <Text>
          Title: {this.state.titles}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey so I ran your exact code except i replaced

```
this.setState({titles: json.title, photos: json.url.replace('http','https')});
```

with

```
this.setState( {
  title: json.title,
  photos: json.url,
} )
```

and it works fine for me, it simply gives me the error for not having an empty string as uri which is expected.

Comment: Am I missing something that the "this.state.photos" is not passing on properly inside of 
    <Image source ={{ uri: this.state.photos }}  />
in order for the image to load properly?

Comment: so state.photos was logging fine and the url was a valid one too. Although you should accommodate for when the url is blank( if the api is taking longer than the render). I suggest use a placeholder image if state.photos is blank or empty. That should get rid of the warning.

Comment: I quickly transfer it to my mac and it works on the ios emulator. I'll have to find out what's not working on my windows PC, expo & my Google XL phone. Thanks for the help! Much appreciated!

Comment: thats strange, just to let you know i tested it on windows with an android emulator sunning API 25.

Comment: i think its probably due to ansyc call.

Comment: it is working for me also @NemiShah is right. I am running on android simulator. no need to change any line of code i jut copy paste your code and boom its working :)